# Custom Login JSP page Springboot + SpringSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new in springboot and I'm triying to implement a custom login. It's not working, it always appear the default spring security login. Any help ?
I've been looking for a solution but I can't find anything that fit in my project. Please, any idea? You can see the project here :

[download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kuJzSo_ayUlRXeOFZjQzavoKrf9i1Bgi)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // add a reference to our security data source

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securityDataSource")
    private DataSource securityDataSource;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // use jdbc authentication ... oh yeah!!!       
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employees/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/fancy-login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try at first like this:

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/fancy-login.html")
            .permitAll();
  }
```

put your fancy-login.html to resources/static/fancy-login.html.